# SwiftUI crash - accessing attribute in a different namespace:

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, crash

I have crashlog from my iOS app. Message saying that
**AttributeGraph precondition failure: accessing attribute in a different namespace:** 836264.
Can somebody explain me what this mean? App try access element with id 836262 and it failed? Or what exactly is different namespace error?

It showing also this error message - AG::non_fatal_precondition_failure(char const*, ...).

I don't know how to simulate it, but it happens on iOS 16.4.1 and one user have this problem frequently (attribute value changed).

I don't using namespaces in SwiftUI. Did swiftUI using something on background? I have here lazyGrid with some VStacks and HStacks.

There is some important messege from stack trace:

```
3  AttributeGraph                 0x2852c AG::non_fatal_precondition_failure(char const*, ...) + 210
4  AttributeGraph                 0x4884 AG::Graph::input_value_ref_slow(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, AG::AttributeID, unsigned int, AGSwiftMetadata const*, unsigned char&, long) + 644
5  AttributeGraph                 0x6840 AGGraphGetInputValue + 236
6  SwiftUI                        0x5f160 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_112 + 4800
```

I test application on some devices trying to simulate error, but it never happened to me or other people. This error occur only two people (by crash analytics), so it's some special case. I just want to know what exactly error message mean. I can't find same error message here. I just want fix this problem and find what causing this problem.

**EDIT:**
For generating elements id i using hasher.combine(), because I don't getting uniqued id from BE. Maybe this could be problem?

Code for generating  -

```swift
func getId(_ widgetNumber: Int, _ widgetLocationNumber: Int, _ widgetLocationRow: Int, _ widgetType: String) -> Int {
    var hasher = Hasher()
    hasher.combine(widgetNumber)
    hasher.combine(widgetLocationNumber)
    hasher.combine(widgetLocationRow)
    hasher.combine(widgetType)

    return hasher.finalize()
}
```

LazyGrid

```swift
LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
  ForEach(Array(viewModel.widgets.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { index, widget in
      WidgetContainerView(widget)
          .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()) // we don't want grayed highlight on cells after user interaction
      if index == 0 && !viewModel.liveWidget.isEmpty {
          LiveFeedWidgetView(viewModel.liveWidget, scrollView)
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a suspicion: make absolutely sure, that you don't have views with the same id. Your function `getId(_:_:_:_:)` does not strictly ensure this. For a quick test, initialise the ID with a `UUID`.

Comment: Edit: you may want to test, if it crashes when you explicitly craft the case, where you have at least two identical IDs (in a unit test).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I debug little more and it's seems that hash id are very big numbers so it can't be this problem. I had same ID's before, because we had duplicated data on BE and app not crashed, it's just start blinking (because reusing views). So I think problem be somewhere else.